# cant bind to datagrid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

```
   <mesh:SecurePanel runat="server" ID="retentionInvoiceDue" WebMasters="true" Admins="true" style="text-align:left; font-size:small;">
            <a class="alert" ID="a1">Alerts</a>
            <br>
            <asp:Panel ID="panelToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue" runat="server" 
                CssClass="retentionLinksOnHomePage" Visible="true">
                <asp:DataGrid ID="datagridToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue" runat="server" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateColumn>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <span>Site
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="promptRententionInvoiceLink" CommandArgument='<%# Bind ("id") %>' OnCommand="getSessionVariableForWorkSiteID" runat="server">
                                        <asp:Label id="labelBindfromHomeToInvoice" runat="server" Text="<%# Bind('Site_Name') %>"/>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>retention due for invoicing 
                                </span>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:DataGrid>
             </asp:Panel>
    </mesh:SecurePanel>
```

In cs file I have in page load:

```
  Context db = new Context();

        var allWorkSites =
            (from worksites in db.Work_Sites
             select worksites).Distinct().ToList();

        List<Object> chosenInvoicesForRetention = new List<Object>();

        foreach (Work_Site worksite in allWorkSites)
        {
            if (!worksite.Invoicing_Complete)
            {
                Invoice lastInvoice = worksite.Invoices.OrderBy(w => w.id).LastOrDefault();

                if (lastInvoice != null)
                {
                    if (lastInvoice.Invoice_Date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(0 - worksite.Number_of_Months))
                    {
                        chosenInvoicesForRetention.Add(worksite);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        if (chosenInvoicesForRetention.Count == 0)
        {
            panelToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue.Visible = false;
        }

        else
        {
            datagridToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue.DataSource = chosenInvoicesForRetention;
            datagridToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

---

Why am I getting the error:
panelToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue
& 
datagridToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue does not exist??

---

EDIT:
I should mention that this code works fine from a different page on my prject, i just copied it over as I want to use it again, but change the table it is being linked too...why would it work from one page and not another?

Also removed the secure panel but still doesnt work

Anyone have any ideas? Would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what is `<mesh:SecurePanel>` if it user control then have you proper register it on the page.?

Comment: yes its a user control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you'll need to use `FindControl` to reference any controls within the `SecurePanel`.

Try placing the following above the places they're referenced in your code-behind.

```
var datagridToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue = 
    (DataGrid)retentionInvoiceDue.FindControl("datagridToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue");

var panelToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue =
    (Panel)retentionInvoiceDue.FindControl("panelToPromptRetentionInvoiceDue");
```

Comment: thanks for that...seems to find the panel and datagrid but now it is saying 'retentionInvoiceDue' in (DataGrid)retentionInvoiceDue.FindControl("datagridToPromptReten.....does not exist in the current context

Comment: Then you're definitely looking at a problem with how your control is registered.  Whatever `mesh:SecurePanel` is...